# Relationship between fracture of solid plates and its curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, solid-state-physics

I do some school projects about fracture of glass, my assumption is this phenomenon related to the curvature of these plates, specifically, fracture starts from the point which is having “maximum” curvature (means principal curvature), and by the result of an experiment, this assumption looks like true, but I don’t know how to explain this “theoretically”?

My first trying is proving the small arc length $ds$ and principal curvature has the same point, because I think fracture is the occurred when the length between atom is bigger than its “limit” but I found both of these are mathematically and physically wrong. Can anybody help to physically explain this assumption?

Comment: Fractures occur at the point of maximum stress. And it's true that greater curvature corresponds to greater stress.

Comment: @lemon and it's possible to show relationship between stress and curvature?

Comment: Yep. I'll post an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curvature is just a form of strain, and strain produces stress. Knowing the curvature, you can compute the *strain field* from which you can obtain the *stress field* using [linear elasticity theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_elasticity).

In the case of fracturing, the stress causes cracks to propagate which results in fracturing. The wiki article on [fracture mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fracture_mechanics) is reasonably detailed.

Comment: It should be noted that this assumes an initially flat glass.